# How can I resolve this error? TypeError: Incompatible collection type: obj is not list-like

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to be able to create a blog post, assign a few tags to it at the time of creation, and save the post with associated tags to the DB. I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Tag is not list-like...

Can someone help me fix my code to achieve the above?

Code:

```
postTags = db.Table("postTags", db.Column("postId", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("posts.id"), primary_key=True), db.Column("tagId", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tags.id"), primary_key=True)) # table defining many-to-many between Post and Tag models and tag

class Blogposting(FlaskForm): form to create the post
    author = StringField("Author", [DataRequired()])
    title = StringField("Title", [DataRequired()])
    body = TextAreaField("Body", [DataRequired()])
    published  = BooleanField(default = False)
    postingTags = SelectMultipleField("Posting Tags", coerce=int) #field with the issue
    save = SubmitField("Save")

class Post(db.Model): #db model to create post from form data
    __tablename__ = "posts" 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    postingDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, 
default=datetime.utcnow)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=postTags, 
backref=db.backref("postTag", lazy="dynamic")) # many to many relationship between Post and Tag

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tags"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
tagName = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
posts = db.relationship("Post", secondary=postTags, backref=db.backref("postTag", lazy="dynamic")) # many to many


@app.route("/posts", methods =["GET", "POST"])
def posts():
    blogPostForm = Blogposting()
    blogPostForm.postingTags.choices = [(i.id, i.tagName) for i in db.session.query(Tag).order_by(Tag.tagName).all()] #dynamic assignment of values to the choices attribute of the SelectMuultipleField
    if blogPostForm.validate_on_submit():
        postTag = request.form.getlist(id) # grabbring selected values from selectMultipleField before posting to database
        blogpostEntries = Post(author = blogPostForm.author.data, title =blogPostForm.title.data, body = blogPostForm.body.data, tags= Tag(id=blogPostForm.postingTags.data)) # save the created post to the db with associated tags from the SelectMultipleField
        db.session.add(blogpostEntries)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("blogEntries"))    
    return render_template("posts.html", year=copyRightYear, subtitle="Blog Posts", form=blogPostForm)
```

Comment: maybe there's no answer to the question, because the sqlalchemy ORM can't direct assign a list for a table join through a junction table unless it's directly mapping of the two table .But things may changed, each time using `db.relationship` contains `secondary` attr. It's worth to check whether those kinds of assignment is supported by sql-alchemy or not. But I haven't use if for long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating relationship on the "one side", you either need to pass a list of object to the relationship attribute (`tags`), or just use append (`tags.append()`) method like this:

```
blogpostEntries = Post(author=blogPostForm.author.data, title =blogPostForm.title.data, body=blogPostForm.body.data)

for tag_id in blogPostForm.postingTags.data:
    blogpostEntries.tags.append(Tag.query.get(tag_id))
```

Comment: this works perfectly. I spent 4 days on those two line of codes, but at the end of the day I'm glad that I learned it this way because the answer now makes more sense to me. Thanks all over the place.